# Error with masked_blit in Allegro5

Tags: c++, allegro, allegro5

I use `masked_blit()` in my program to display a .bmp with transparency (using perfect pink). But when I build, it says :

> error: ‘masked_blit’ was not declared in this scope

I included Allegro's .h, and of course I didn't forgot all of these:

```
-lallegro -lallegro_font -lallegro_ttf -lallegro_image
```

here is an excerpt of the code I wrote :

```
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
[...]
 head = al_load_bitmap("head.bmp");
 masked_blit(head, display, 0,0,0,0,10,10);
 al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0,0,0));
 al_draw_bitmap(head, screen_w / 2, screen_h / 2, 0);
[..]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`masked_blit` is Allegro 4 function. It does not exist in Allegro 5.

[Here are graphics functions in Allegro 5](http://alleg.sourceforge.net/a5docs/5.0.9/graphics.html)

`al_draw_bitmap_region` is the most similiar function to `masked_blit`, but transparency rules are different (8-bit alpha channel vs 1-bit pink color as alpha).

`al_convert_mask_to_alpha(ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bitmap, ALLEGRO_COLOR mask_color)` may be useful here.

Comment: All Allegro 5 functions begin with `al_`, so it should be easy to tell when you are looking at Allegro 4 code, docs, tutorials, etc.